# Creating a function for unstacking a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have a data frame that is somewhat structured like this

```
InvoiceNo  Month  Year  Size
     1       1    2014   7
     2       1    2014   8
     3       2    2014   11
     4       3    2015   9
     5       7    2015   8.5
```

and so on...

I am trying to create a function that will segment the Dframe by year, and group by the size and the month, and then count the InvoiceNo, and then finally unstack that dataframe.

What I have been doing is something like this:

```
x = 2014

def Year_calc(df):
    return df[df['Year'] == x].groupby(['Size','Month']).agg({'InvoiceNo': 'count'}).unstack(0).columns.droplevel(0).fillna(0)
```

and then df2014 = Year_calc(df)

But it returns this output:

```
Float64Index([], dtype='float64', name='Size')
```

Anyone able to point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In your df it is InvoiceNO  not InvoiceNo

Comment: Apologies but that was a Typo. In my actual notebook, both are specified as 'InvoiceNo'.

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby`, `count`, and `unstack`:

```
res = df.groupby(['Year', 'Size', 'Month',]).InvoiceNo.count().unstack(0, fill_value=0)
res

Year        2014  2015
Size Month            
7.0  1         1     0
8.0  1         1     0
8.5  7         0     1
9.0  3         0     1
11.0 2         1     0
```

Or, equivalently with `pivot_table`:

```
res = df.pivot_table(index=['Size', 'Month'], 
                     columns='Year', 
                     values='InvoiceNo', 
                     aggfunc='count', 
                     fill_value=0)

Year        2014  2015
Size Month            
7.0  1         1     0
8.0  1         1     0
8.5  7         0     1
9.0  3         0     1
11.0 2         1     0
```

Compare this as follows:

```
res[2014] > res[2015]
```

---

Alternatively, just compute this for the desired year:

```
(df[df.Year.eq(2014)]
     .groupby(['Size', 'Month'])
     .InvoiceNo
     .count()
     .unstack(1, fill_value=0))

Month  1  2
Size       
7.0    1  0
8.0    1  0
11.0   0  1
```

Comment: That would work, but I am trying to create a separate data frame for each year for comparison.

Comment: @KyleMcComb I've given you some options. Really, it shouldn't be too hard to slice out the columns you want and compare.

Comment: @KyleMcComb Do `df.Year.unique()` and you'll have a list of all the years you've got.

Answer (score 1):

`df.apply` either passes a row or column as a Series object - depending on the axis you specify. It does not pass the entire dataframe.

If you want to apply a function to the entire dataframe, how about `df2014 = Year_calc(df)`?

You should also consider passing the year as a parameter to the function - so it’s clear what the year_calc function is doing.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I don't get an error anymore, but now I get an array looking like:
Float64Index([], dtype='float64', name='Size')

Comment: Agree. doesn't have to create function for above case

Answer (score 0):

here is the input data :

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'InvoiceNo':[1,2,3,4,5],'Month':[1,1,2,3,7],'Year':[2014,2014,2014,2015,2015],'Size':[7,8,11,9,8.5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

**SOLUTION 1 :**

using previous answers and the elements you gave, here is the function I managed to write :

```
def Year_calc(data, year):

# grouping the by Size and month
t1 = data.loc[data.Year == year].groupby(['Size','Month'])

#count the number of Invoice for the given year
t2 = t1.InvoiceNo.count().unstack(0, fill_value=0)
return t2
```

here is the returned table for year = 2014 :

```
Size   7.0   8.0   11.0
Month                  
1         1     1     0
2         0     0     1
```

**SOLUTION 2**
Since you removed the year as parameter, it seems better to do few adjustments, you either select the rows by year before performing the group by or you group by year, Month, size then select the rows corresponding to the year you want.

```
def Year_calc(data):

    # grouping the by Year, Size and month
    t1 = data.groupby(['Year','Month','Size'])

    #count the number of Invoice for the given year
    t2 = t1.InvoiceNo.count().unstack(2, fill_value=0)
    return t2
```

the unfiltered output would be :

```
Size    7.0     8.0     8.5     9.0     11.0
Year    Month                   
2014    1   1   1   0   0   0
        2   0   0   0   0   1
2015    3   0   0   0   1   0
        7   0   0   1   0   0
```

let's suppose you need the data from 2015, then you type :

```
tdf = Year_calc(data = df)
tdf.xs(2015) 
# or
test.loc[(2015,),:]
```

the result returned :

```
Size    7.0     8.0     8.5     9.0     11.0
Month                   
    3    0       0       0       1       0
    7    0       0       1       0       0
```

Please, check this article for multi-index slicing : [here](https://www.somebits.com/~nelson/pandas-multiindex-slice-demo.html)

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: I had to remove the year from the parameter, but after doing that it returned a flat frame with 2 Verticle dimensions: Month, and Size, with no data in the frame.